# Consistency strength of weakly inaccessibles without $\mathsf{GCH}$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Actually, the thing is to bypass $V=L$. So, is there a way to prove that (if consistent) $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can't prove that there exists a weakly inaccessible without first showing that $\mathsf{GCH}$ is relatively consistent? Obviously, if we can show that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ doesn't prove the *consistency* of a  weakly inaccessible is much better.

The only really similar question I found is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162740/212120), and I wasn't much too thorough in my web search because I'm pretty sure that this is just a curiosity.

**PS.** Answers using Easton magic are not allowed!

Comment: Does you accept using $L_\kappa$ directly?

Comment: @HanulJeon The point is to avoid the $L$ construction altogether. I don't know, perhaps some wise reflection trick... Good luck!