# Proving/disproving that weakly inaccessible cardinals imply $V_{\kappa}$ models ZFC

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm trying a problem which asks which axioms of ZFC hold - under the assumption that there exists a *weakly* inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ - inside $V_{\kappa}$ ($\kappa$ being such a cardinal).

I am relatively sure I have argued that everything holds except replacement which I am struggling with. I don't seem to have used the weakly inaccessible cardinal part with the others, so I am guessing this is where it comes in, but I'm not even sure what I'm meant to be considering. If I take $x\in V_{\kappa}$ and consider some function defined on $x$, am I considering functions into $V_{\kappa}$ only? Even if this is the case, how do I use regularity of $\kappa$ to argue $f(x)\in V_{\kappa}?$

Comment: Funny! I recently asked a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2098832/212120) in the same spirit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, then Replacement holds in $V_\kappa$; but if $\kappa$ is only weakly inaccessible, then there is some $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $2^\lambda\geq\kappa$.

Now, ZF proves that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal, but we can now find a well-ordered set inside $V_\kappa$ whose order type is $\kappa$, and therefore is not isomorphic to any ordinal *inside* $V_\kappa$.

Interestingly, the regularity of $\kappa$ is *not* what gives you Replacement. In fact, the least $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZF has cofinality $\omega$ (if such $\kappa$ exists, of course). However, regularity does provide you with an guarantee that if all sets inside $V_\kappa$ have cardinality less than $\kappa$, then any function applied to them will also have cardinality less than $\kappa$.

Comment: Thank you. This is all quite new to me so I'm a little (or very!) confused. 1. what material are we using to show $\exists \lambda<\kappa$ with $\kappa\leqslant 2^{\lambda}$ if $\kappa$ weakly inacc.? 2. I am having trouble relating such a $\lambda$ to stuff in $V_{\kappa}$. We cannot have $x\in V_{\kappa}$ with $|x|=\lambda$ else power-set also fails (?); so is it that there is an $x\subseteq V_{\kappa}$ with that size?

[feel free to "explain like I'm five", feeling quite lost]

Comment: I don't usually talk with five year olds. Please point at your parent or legal guardian, and I will get them. For (1) by definition of weakly inaccessible which isn't strongly inaccessible. For (2) why?

Comment: (1) Oh right - so, is the assumption/axiom "there is a weakly inacc. cardinal" enough to justify the existence such a $\lambda$? I thought it was consistent with ZFC that all weak inaccessibles are strongly inaccessible (through independence of GHC). Sorry if I'm slow. (2) so what is confusing me is that power set is fine, so it's not clear to me why $2^{\lambda}\geq \kappa$ breaks replacement. What do $\lambda$ and $2^{\lambda}$ correspond to in terms of $V_{\kappa}$ (or $V$ I suppose)?

Comment: As I wrote. if $\kappa$ is *strongly* inaccessible, there is no such $\lambda$. If $\kappa$ *is* weakly inaccessible ***AND NOT*** strongly inaccessible, then there is such $\lambda$ *by definition*.

Comment: Ok yes, so in the case of this particular problem (where I am only told $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible and nothing more), is it true that I cannot give a definitive answer as to whether $V_{\kappa}$ models replacement?

Comment: No. You cannot.

Comment: Ah right, odd question to ask then - thank you. With regards to point (2) [outside of the problem now, and assuming weak but not strong], could you explain what role $\lambda$ is playing in terms of elements inside $V_{\kappa}?$ Essentially, how do I relate "$\lambda<\kappa$ and $2^{\lambda}\geqslant\kappa$" to stuff in our world $V_{\kappa}$?

Comment: There is a set of *cardinality* $2^\lambda$ in $V_\kappa$, (since $\lambda<\kappa$ means that $\lambda\in V_\kappa$, and therefore $\mathcal P(\lambda)\in V_\kappa$). But now not every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal *inside $V_\kappa$*.

Comment: Ohhh okay so hang on - I think the problem has been that I understood $2^{\lambda}$ as $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$. So are we saying that the function $\alpha\mapsto 2^{\alpha}$ breaks replacement because it is sending ordinals to ordinals and the ordinal $2^{\lambda}$ is not necessarily in $V_{\kappa}?$ [and by the way, massive thanks for taking the time to reply - you're incredibly patient!]

Comment: Both things. $2^\lambda$ *is* the *set* $\mathcal P(\lambda)$, which is an element of $V_\kappa$. But while it can be well-ordered, and this well-order is an element of $V_\kappa$ as well, this well-ordering is *not* isomorphic to any ordinal inside $V_\kappa$. You can look at it as the function mapping $\lambda$ to the cardinal $2^\lambda$ as well, though.

Comment: Ok, so generally for any cardinal $\delta \geq \kappa$, well-orderings of size $\delta$ are not isomorphic to ordinals inside $V_{\kappa}$. This is what I don't fully follow? It's probably basic, but I'm missing it.

Comment: What are the ordinals inside ¢V_\kappa$?

Comment: It clicked, ordinals have rank themselves. I'm taking baby steps, but it all makes sense now, thank you.